# Changing DHCP server on Network ramifications?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, dhcp

On our small business network, we've unfortunately got our Cisco RV220 router acting as the DHCP server, but all of our client PCs and Servers are pointing at our Windows Domain Controller running on Windows Server 2012 for DNS.

I would like to switch our DHCP server to the Windows DC. What are the potential ramifications of a) disabling DHCP from our router and b) enabling from the Windows DC? Will all leased IPs suddenly change?

As of right now it does not seem that when our router assigns an IP to a client on our network that the DNS server is getting the heads up, so we suffer from a lot of connection issues when trying to use RDP to connect to client machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Will all leased IPs suddenly change?` - In all likelihood your clients will get a different ip address than the one they got from the router the next time they go through the rebinding phase. That, in and of itself, shouldn't cause any problems.

Note that I said `rebinding`, not `renewing`. During the renewal phase the DHCP client will attempt to communicate with the DHCP server that granted the lease. Failing to do so (because you've disabled the DHCP service on the router) the clients will then attempt to communicate with any DHCP server during the rebinding phase, during which time the new DHCP server will either allow the DHCP client to continue to use the leased ip address (which is unlikely since the new server will have no information about the existing lease), or the server will deny the request to continue using the leased ip address in which case the client will request a new ip address (this is the likely outcome).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently. The procedure I followed was to setup the DHCP server on the Win server. When all was done, i turned off the dhcp on the router and restarted the dhcp server on the win server. To test, I went to a DHCP client and did a ipconfig /renew. All was fine. The other devices picked up a new IP from the Win DHCP at next renew. If, for some reason, it did not work, I asked people with sufficient rights to run `ipconfig /renew`, all other unfortunately had to reboot. All in all, worse case, a reboot of the client is required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've been paranoid about doing this because as of right now everything kind of works fine and I didn't want to screw up everyone's work day even though I know this needs to be done sooner or later. This has given me a bit more confidence.